# Get all comments of public media with instagram api (without access token)

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

For text-mining project , I want to get all comments of specific media (image or video) from **public account** on Instagram and based on developers documentation any `get` action needs `Access Token` for security issues.

According to similar questions on internet, it is not possible to access comments endpoint without access token , But I don't know and can't understand the reason of using this limitation for **public** accounts.

I checked the ajax response with firebug for comments but I think this is not the good solution . is there any better solution ?

Answer (score 2):

most likely your answer would be: no, there shouldn't be any better solution

the access token is a measure to protect against DoS and DDoS https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DoS#Distributed_DoS

so there is a strong rationale behind it, and measures should be in place to avoid you to work around it

Comment: BTW, DoS would not be the only reason for such token, it also can serve other goals (like stats, any sort of tracking, etc)